# Uncaught SmartyCompilerException: Syntax Error in template in server migration

Tags: nginx, smarty, prestashop-1.6

I'm transfering a Prestashop server to another server. The origin server is a CentOS with Apache and the destination is a Ubuntu with Nginx.

The problem is that I got this error when I open a product link in Prestashop:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SmartyCompilerException: Syntax Error in
>   template
>   "/var/www/loja/themes/default-bootstrap/product.tpl" on line
>   48 "{/addJsDefL}{/strip}{/if}" unexpected closing tag in
>   /var/www/loja/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php:667
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/loja/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_compilebase.php(170):
>   Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase->trigger_template_error('unexpected
>   clos...', 48) #1
>   /var/www/loja/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_compile_private_registered_block.php(85):
>   Smarty_Internal_CompileBase->closeTag(Object(Smarty_Internal_SmartyTemplateCompiler), 'addJsDefL') #2
>   /var/www/loja/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php(475):
>   Smarty_Internal_Compile_Private_Registered_Block->compile(Array,
>   Object(Smarty_Internal_SmartyTemplateCompiler), Array,
>   'addJsDefLclose', NULL) #3
>   /var/www/loja/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php(417):
>   Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase->callTagC in
>   /var/www/loja/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php
>   on line 667

It seems that, for example, the code "{/addJsDefL}" need to have spaces like this "{ /addJsDefL }"

But in the old server the code "{/addJsDefL}" works without any problems.

So, is there a way to make the new server work with the old way? Maybe a parameter in the server?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you checked the locale configuration if is the same on both servers? Are you sure the file exactly the same?

Comment: @sadlyblue, locale configuration was different but I changed to be the same and it hasn't solved the problem. 
The files are the same. I compacted the files and transfered to the other server.
Thanks for giving a try